# LF database model; 1 website with multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have a website with a simple PHP login. Now, there a three databases, each for one customer (there coming more and more with the time). So every customer got a database. Eacht database has the same tables. All users are going to be allowed to login on the same website.

I need a database model for the users, do i create one database with all users just for the login ? What is the best practice for this ? How do i handle the check of the credentials on multiple databases ?

I hope you understand what i mean.

Thank you, Louis

Comment: This sounds like a problem caused by very bad database design

Comment: Like @RiggsFolly said this is a really bad database design. You should handle all with one database and use foreign keys to reference everything

Comment: 3 DB for one website? Are you sure?

Comment: What is exactly the point in having a different database per customer if you need to share user information? You didn't achieve anything, and I agree with @RiggsFolly - this is a very bad database design.

Comment: I thought it is better to seperate the customers data - but if you say to handle all of them in one database, i am going to do that.

Comment: If you separate data by creating different databases, then what problem did you solve? You think that databases behave like folders - they don't, this is handled completely differently behind the scenes. If your system is such that you have multitenancy and you absolutely need to have users from every customer available globally (as you do, because you can't log in otherwise), then you need to save all the data in the same database. Adding simple `customer_id` column where appropriate lets you differentiate between what belongs to which customer.

Comment: Okay, i have been very uncertain about the handling of the customers data, because it is my first time and i dont want to do something wrong with data security. Thank you for your stimulation about that.